# ViewModel calling a method of a user control (web browser)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, methods, controls

I am trying to program in **MVVM** and I have the following use case:

1. A `TextBox`'s text is bound to a property in the VM
2. A `Button` is command bound to a relay command
3. When the user presses the `Button`, the web browser's `Navigate(url)` method is called with the URL being the text in the `TextBox`

Above is the use case I want to create, but 1 and 2 is possible using the **MVVM** design pattern, but I could not find an adequate way to invoke the browser's `Navigate()` method. First of all, is it possible to call a method of a control from VM (please let me know if there is a way)? And in the above use case, what would be the appropriate way to structure the program if it is not possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

- Add a property `MyUrl` to your ViewModel
- Bind `MyUrl` to your WebBrower's `Source` property

Make sure the property implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Then your Xaml:

```
<WebBrowser Source="{Binding MyUrl}" />
```

**What if you REALLY wanted to call a UI method from the ViewModel?**

If you ever do run into a situation where you absolutely need to call a *method* on a UI control for instance, you can hook up `events` on the ViewModel and then your UI registers to this event and does something UI specific...

VM code...

```
//... some VM logic
EpicNavigateEvent(url) // raise event, allowing UI to handle how
```

In your code-behind on your view (this is the part where some MVVM purests freak), you could register the event:

```
myVm.Navigate += doSomeNavigation;
...
public void doSomeNavigation(string url)
{
   // call Navigate
}
```

I've successfully used this approach for applications where we have a single ViewModel layer and multiple technologies hooked up the views (WinForms, WPF and Asp.Net).

If you're looking for something more ***elegant***, have a look at the [User Interaction Patterns on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494(v=pandp.40).aspx#sec10).
The concept is the same though: Call something on the VM and the View is handles it appropriately.

Common scenarios for this type of approach is want to show a message to the user from the VM. Your VM should raise an event saying: `ShowMyMessage("You're awesome")`, then your UI is notified and handles it: `MessageBox.Show(msg)` or whatever.

As long as you stick to there rules you should be golden:

- ViewModels should **NOT** be concerned about UI code
- Views must **ONLY** handle the presentation of the data provided by your ViewModels.
- Don't overcomplicate it. [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)...

Comment: Thank you Neils for your help. For my current project I will use your suggested method of binding Source to a property in my ViewModel.